# How do C# threads cause memory leaks when they already finished?

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-leaks, mono, xamarin

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
namespace testt
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static List<TestObject> testjobs = new List<TestObject> ();
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
            addTask (); //put a breakpoint here
            Thread.Sleep (5000);
            deleteObj ();
            while (true) {
                Console.WriteLine ("MAIN STILL EXISTS!");
                Thread.Sleep (1500);
                GC.Collect ();
            }
        }
        public static void addTask()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                testjobs.Add (new TestObject ());
                testjobs [i].Start ();
            }
        }

        public static void deleteObj()
        {
            for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
            {
                testjobs [0].dispose ();
                testjobs.RemoveAt (0);
            }
            Console.WriteLine (testjobs.Count);
        }

    }

    public class TestObject
    {

        private bool _isStopRequested;
        private Thread _thread;
        public void Start()
        {
            _thread = new Thread(ThreadRoutine);
            _thread.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _isStopRequested = true;
            if(!_thread.Join(5000))
            {
                _thread.Abort();
            }
        }

        public void dispose(){
            this.Stop ();
            this._thread.Abort ();
            this._thread=null;
        }


        private void ThreadRoutine()
        {
            //while(!_isStopRequested) //THIS CAUSES THE MEMORY LEAK!!!
            {
            Thread.Sleep (1);
            }
            Console.WriteLine ("THREAD FINISHED");
        }

        ~TestObject(){
            Console.WriteLine ("===================TESTOBJECT DESTROYED!!===============");
        }
    }
}
```

If you run it with the `//while(!_isStopRequested)` uncommented, the `TestObject` instances will not be destroyed, i.e their destructor methods will not be called.

If you run it as is, then only 4-8 objects will be destroyed, not all 10 of them.

Why does this happen when the threads have fully exited? I checked with the Xamarin debugger and the threads were definitely stopped. If you put a breakpoint in Xamarin at addTask(); then you can see that 10 threads

My only explanation for this is that the thread somehow holds a reference back to their parent object TestObject instance even after they have finished. How can a thread hold a reference to their parent object when the thread has already finished?

Also, if I change `Thread.Sleep(1)` to `Thread.Sleep(5000)`, the `TestObjects` also stop being collected.

Also, as it is, only some TestObjects get collected whilst others don't.

Why do these things happen? How can I ensure that ALL the TestObjects get garbage collected by the time the `deleteObj()` function returns?

EDIT: I just tested the exact same code in Visual Studio (.NET) and all of the objects were garbage collected regardless of whether if that line was commented out or not.

Therefore I now consider this issue to be a Mono-specific problem and there was no memory leak to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finalizers are not deterministic.  You cannot rely on them being called.

If it is vitally important for your program to clean up the resource in question then you should be explicitly disposing of it, and not relying on a finalizer.

If cleaning up the resource would be nice, but you don't really care all that much if the finializer gets to it or not, then you can choose to not explicitly dispose of the unmanaged resources.

Also note that making a managed object *eligible* for garbage collection doesn't necessarily mean that it will be garbage collected.  It means it *can* be collected whenever the collector feels like it.

Finally, recognize that aborting a thread is another unreliable thing to do.  The thread do.  There are a number of ways for a thread that has been requested to abort will not successfully do so, or where it will cause any number of different types of problems when it does.  You should avoid using `Thread.Abort` unless the thread in question was designed to be aborted, and you have a strong understanding of all of the many possible pitfalls of trying to reason about a program that could throw an exception between any two operations.

Comment: So how do I explicitly dispose of the object?

Comment: @joesmith Implement `IDisposable` and always call `Dispose` on the object when you want any unmananged objects to be disposed of.  If you don't have any unmanaged objects, then you shouldn't be worrying about it at all and allowing the GC to clean up the object whenever it feels like it.

Comment: The problem is that my memory usage continues to increase even after my objects have been "deleted". The object doesn't contain "resources" other than a few boolean variables that I can see. Are threads resources as well? I think the threads were also terminated. How do I make it free all the memory?

Comment: @joesmith Your program is just full of unreliable operations that you simply cannot rely on doing *anything*.  With so many operations that could do any number of undefined things, the odds of something unexpected happening are quite high.  Instead right programs that are deterministic, and that can be reliably reasoned about to performed in expected ways, if you plan on having any expectations about what your program does.

Comment: Which operations are unreliable, which are reliable, and how do I replace the unreliable operations with reliable operations?

Comment: @joesmith I go over that in my answer.

Comment: I don't see any mention of reliable operations in your answer. You just talked about "finalisers" and Thread.Abort. What should I use instead?

Comment: Well I mention three of them in it.

Comment: I have read your answer 20 times over the past 2 hours and cannot find 3 lines of code that tell me how to properly dispose of objects. Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: @joesmith To properly dispose of an object that has unmanaged resources  you need to explicitly call `Dispose` on it, rather than relying on the finalizer to run.  If you have no unmanaged resources then you shouldn't be either disposing of the object or using a finalizer.

Comment: Okay so from what I understand, unmanaged resources are files and network connections. Since the code I posted did not open files or network connections, that means all of it is managed, and that I didn't have to worry about any memory leak, so I was worried about nothing. Is this correct?

Comment: @joesmith That said, all of the things that I mention in my answer as problems are real problems.  You aren't necessarily leaking memory, but the these issues can cause any number of other types of problems.